# How to use anonymized datasets?

Tags: data-mining

I'm making my first steps in association rules.

I found this topic ([Supermarket dataset for Apriori algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9754769/supermarket-dataset-for-apriori-algorithm)).
Then I tried to use the data suggested in answer2, but when I see the explanation of the dataset, doesn't seems to keep any correlation with the actual data.

About the data set, the author explains: "Each record in the data set contains information about the date of purchase (variable ’date’), the receipt number (variable ’receipt nr’)..."

and in the first record of the data I see:

> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29

In the second:

> 30 31 32

I suppose that this is because the data set has been "anonymized", but how should I "translate" variables to data?

Answer (score 1):

From a quick look I assume that this is only a subset of the original data, in a typical "basket" format.
Each line is a transaction, and each number is an item.

No, without additional data source you will not be able to tell which items these were.

So it's mostly good for testing that your algorithm returns *something* on real data, but you won't really know *what* it found.

You might want to look at the `supermarket.arff` file that IIRC comes with Weka. It has at least some product categoires labeled (e.g. "frozen foods").